# Discussing the differentiability of a multivariable function at origin.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I recently was unable to solve a Question on differntiability as follows:

> Discuss the differentiability of $f$ at $(0,0)$ , where
> $$f(x,y) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             xy(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2) & \quad  \text{if} \space (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
>             0 & \quad \text{if} \space (x,y) = (0,0) \\
>         \end{array}
>     \right.
>  $$

I knew the necessary and sufficient condition for differentiability as:

> $\lim_{Δ\rho\to0}(Δf-df)/Δ\rho=0$ , where $Δ\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

But I have never used this condition before and am facing issues, namely computing $Δf$ (which seems to be too tiresome to compute) and what to substitute for $dx$ ad $dy$ in $df$ . Also, I tried to change to polar coordinates but couldn't do anything with $Δr$ when $r\to0$. ($r$ was $Δ\rho$ in that case)

I'm out of ideas. Would someone please help?

Comment: If $f$ were differentiable at $(0,0)$, what would be the perfect candidate for the total derivative of $f$ at $(0,0)$?

Comment: @Koro $df = f_x dx + f_y dy$ , I think.

Comment: No. That's not total derivative. The total derivative at $(0,0)$ in this case is supposed to be a linear map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$. So the perfect candidate for the total derivative will be $(f_x(0,0),f_y(0,0))$.

Comment: Oh, I am not very familiar with these terms yet.

Comment: @Koro Can the problem be solved by using the condition given?

Comment: Did you find the partial derivatives $f_x, f_y$? What did you get? I think you should incorporate that in your post. Also, I think that you wanted to say “if $(x,y)\ne 0$“ in the definition of the function.

Comment: @Koro and the function should be $f(x,y)$, correct?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw: yes, considering the multivariable tag in OP.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I've edited it now.

Comment: and what about "if $(x,y)=(0,0)$" in the definition of the function?

Comment: @Koro Sorry for that, I don't know how to type =/=

Comment: @Shashwat1337 it’s “\neq” 

Comment: @RadialArmSaw Okay, thanks!

Comment: @Shashwat1337 no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|xy| \leq x^2+y^2 \Longrightarrow \left|\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\right| \leq |x^2-y^2| \leq x^2+y^2$. I.e., $\Delta f \leq \Delta \rho^2$, which proves that $f$ is differentiable and $df = 0$. Indeed: $\left| \frac{\Delta f - 0}{\Delta \rho}\right| < |\Delta \rho|$ and thus $\lim_{\Delta\rho\rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta f - 0}{\Delta \rho} = 0$

Comment: Thank you very much!